# Run an example from 'npm phantom' page

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

Download and run install.js **[npm phantom](https://npmjs.org/package/phantomjs)** >> *PhantomJS is already installed at /usr/local/bin/phantomjs*. Create a file pizza.js with working Phantomjs example and pizzaTest.js to test it.

```
var childProcess = require('child_process')
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs')
var binPath = phantomjs.path

var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, 'pizza.js'),
]

childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
})
```

an recive an error:

```
/home/khaljava/coder/phantom/pizzaTest.js:6
  path.join(__dirname, 'pizza.js'),
  ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to add

```
var path = require('path');
```